# CMake source_group() not working correctly with hierarchical project setup

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

After a change to make a CMake project have hierarchical folder management, source_group() no longer seems to be working correctly. CMake just dumps everything into the default filters.

I've tried various regexes to get the relative file path from the parent for every source file and even hard coding the source files in the parent CMakeLists.txt just to see if that was the issue. I've also tried regenerating the VS project a couple times after these changes.

Here's sample files for your viewing pleasure:

Parent CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.3)
set(SRCS)
add_subdirectory(PlatformDetection)
include_directories (.)
add_library(SystemAbstraction STATIC ${SRCS})
set_property(TARGET SystemAbstraction PROPERTY FOLDER "Engine")
set_target_properties(SystemAbstraction PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
install (TARGETS SystemAbstraction
     ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
```

Child CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.3)
add_subdirectory(Compilers)
set(SRCS ${SRCS} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

and

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.3)      
set (COMPILER_DETECTION_HEADERS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CompilerDetection.h)
set (COMPILER_DETECTION_SRC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CompilerDetection.cpp)    
source_group("Header Files\\Platform Detection\\Compilers" FILES     ${COMPILER_DETECTION_HEADERS})
source_group("Source Files\\Platform Detection\\Compilers" FILES         ${COMPILER_DETECTION_SRC})  
set(SRCS ${SRCS} ${COMPILER_DETECTION_HEADERS} ${COMPILER_DETECTION_SRC} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a direct copy of @BlamKiwi 's answer but with an absolute path added to fix problems seen with relative only paths (and put into a macro)
I would comment on his but i have no reputation.

```
MACRO(GROUP_SRC SRCS)
  foreach(FILE ${SRCS}) 
    #convert source file to absolute
    get_filename_component(ABSOLUTE_PATH "${FILE}" ABSOLUTE)
    # Get the directory of the absolute source file
    get_filename_component(PARENT_DIR "${ABSOLUTE_PATH}" DIRECTORY)
    # Remove common directory prefix to make the group
    string(REPLACE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" "" GROUP "${PARENT_DIR}")
    # Make sure we are using windows slashes
    string(REPLACE "/" "\\" GROUP "${GROUP}")
    # Group into "Source Files" and "Header Files"
    if ("${FILE}" MATCHES ".*\\.cpp")
      set(GROUP "Source Files${GROUP}")
    elseif("${FILE}" MATCHES ".*\\.h")
      set(GROUP "Header Files${GROUP}")
    endif()
    source_group("${GROUP}" FILES "${FILE}")
  endforeach()
ENDMACRO(GROUP_SRC)
```

Answer (score 10):

I fixed my problem by writing a foreach loop which iterates over the source files and groups them by their relative path and if they're header or source files. Then just run this as a macro in every place where you define a library/executable.

```
foreach(FILE ${SRCS}) 
    # Get the directory of the source file
    get_filename_component(PARENT_DIR "${FILE}" DIRECTORY)

    # Remove common directory prefix to make the group
    string(REPLACE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" "" GROUP "${PARENT_DIR}")

    # Make sure we are using windows slashes
    string(REPLACE "/" "\\" GROUP "${GROUP}")

    # Group into "Source Files" and "Header Files"
    if ("${FILE}" MATCHES ".*\\.cpp")
       set(GROUP "Source Files${GROUP}")
    elseif("${FILE}" MATCHES ".*\\.h")
       set(GROUP "Header Files${GROUP}")
    endif()

    source_group("${GROUP}" FILES "${FILE}")
endforeach()
```

Comment: I think CMake gets all of the relative paths right when the ``source_group`` and ``add_library commands`` are in the same file/folder. Did your problem come about when you moved the ``source_group`` to a child ``CMakeLists.txt``? Thanks for keeping us informed.

Comment: Yes, it did. Either way this for loop is just plain convenient.

Comment: Yes, it is convenient! I just wanted to understand why it became necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to add `set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)`.

Comment: Already enabled by the base CMakeLists.txt that defines the project.